# Using chart.js for Polar chart, How to create each visible value to custom width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, chart.js, chart.js2

[image]

Above is the image of my polar chart & below is code I am using.

```
<div id="sale_process" style="height: 320px; width: auto;">
   <canvas id="sale_process_chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: [ 
           100, 
            90, 
            80, 
            70, 
            60, 
            50 
         ],
        backgroundColor: [
           "#7ab5eb",
           "#444347",
           "#91eb7c",
           "#f7a15b",
           "#7e85e9",
           "#ed5d87"
          ],
        }],
        labels: [
         "40% Branding and Marketing ",
         "20% Gift Code Inventory",
         "18% Legal & Financial Over head",
         "10% IT Infrastructure",
         "8% Bounty & Overhead",
         "4% Management"
       ],
   };

   var ctx = $("#sale_process_chart");
   new Chart(ctx, {
     data: data,
     type: 'polarArea',
     options:{
        legend:{
            position:'right',
            labels: {
                boxWidth:8,
            },
        },
        scale: {
            display: false
        }
    },
});
</script>
```

I want to give all width as per their percent like Blue color should take 40% of chart Black color should take 20% can anyone help me out for it. I don't know how to create custom I went through many links but not able to find solution for this.